# increase size of field in jqgrid advanced searching

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

Is there a way to increase the size of the textbox fields in the advanced searching of jqgrid. The final textbox is squished for some reason. I have inserted an image to show this.

[image: JQGrid Advanced Searching]

Here is the code

```
grid2 = $('#BillInformation').jqGrid({
   ...
   { name: 'DOS_From', index: 'DOS_From', width: 150, align: 'center',
      searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge'],
         dataInit: function (elem) {
            $(elem).datepicker({
               showButtonPanel: true, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true,
               showAnim: 'drop'
            })
         }
      }
   },
   ...
});
```

Comment: Do you know what I need to look for in the CSS file? I figured it was a CSS issue.

Comment: If you have firebug installed for firefox (or the chrome dev tools) you can just figure out the CSS using that and also change the values on the fly to see the effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the `size` attribute of the textbox fields from the Advanced Searching dialog by adding the corresponding property of the [searchoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asearch_config#colmodel_options) option of the `colModel`. For example:

```
searchoptions: {size: 20}
```